# What is the integral of $a^{x-1}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

What is the integral of $$\int a^{x-1}dx?$$

is it $$\frac{a^{x-1}}{\log(a)}  + c?$$

How can we derive the proper integral? Also can you please tell me the definite integral with limits, say b to c?

Comment: If you have a guess of the integral, you can differentiate it to check if it is right.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it is $$\frac{1}{a}\int a^xdx=\frac{1}{a}\frac{a^x}{\ln(a)}+C$$

Comment: Can you tell me the definite integral too please?

Comment: what Limits do you have?

Comment: 1 to 30, these are the limits

Comment: why did you gave me the $-1$?

Comment: I didn't give u the -1.

Comment: ok it was someone else

Comment: you can just plug These values in the formula above, for your Control, it is $$\frac{a^{29}-1}{\log (a)}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what about when the $a<0$

Comment: what is a function $$a^x$$ for real numbers $x$ and $$a>0$$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a>0$, $a,x$ real:

$a^{x-1} =\exp(\ln(a^{x-1}))= $

$\exp((x-1)\ln(a))= \exp(c(x-1))$,

where $c :=\ln(a).$

Use substitution:

$y=c (x-1)$ to integrate $\exp(y).$